# How to assign results to variables?

Tags: functions, array

Here is what I have so far:

```
function get_highest_bid_info(){
    global $wpdb;
    $postid = get_the_id();
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "jwp_bids";
    $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT email, max(bid_amt)
        FROM  $table
        WHERE post_id = '$postid')"
        );
```

Now I want to assign those two values to independent variables such as `$high_bid` and `$high_bidder`. I know the two values are in an array of some sort. I read in the codex but don't ascertain from that How to access and assign them?

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm learning here :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best luck while you learn.

```
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT ID, post_title 
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_status = 'draft' 
        AND post_author = 5
    "
);

foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft ) 
{
    echo $fivesdraft->post_title;
}
```

This example has been sponsored by [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

---

In your case

```
$wpdb->get_results(
```

Should become like:

```
$variable_to_print = $wpdb->get_results(
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't that assign both values ( email, bid_amount) to one variable?? I need to assign email to a variable and bid_amount to another variable.

Comment: Hi @James, it is not good to interfere further at the moment. You must grind  the food yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
function find_highest_bid(){
    global $wpdb;
    $postid = get_the_id();
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "jwp_bids";
    $highest_bid = $wpdb->get_results(
        "Select max(bid_amt) AS bid, bid_time, email
        FROM $table
        WHERE post_id = '1277'", ARRAY_A );
    $highest_bid = array_shift ( $highest_bid );
    $high_bid = $highest_bid['bid'];
    $high_bidder = $highest_bid['email'];
    $bid_time = $highest_bid['bid_time'];
    echo '$'. $high_bid;
    echo ", ";
    echo $high_bidder;
    echo ", ";
    echo $bid_time;
}
```